# Using global $post; with custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, date, globals

I'm working on creating a notification that will indicate when a post is less than a few days old. This is specifically for a custom post type called "news". Is there a way to use `global $post;` with custom post types?

This is my original code.

```
<?php global $post;
    $postdate = str_replace("-", " ",substr($post->post_date, 0,10));
    $postd = explode(" ", $postdate);
    $ageunix = get_the_time('U');
    $days_old_in_seconds = ((time() - $ageunix));
    $days_old = (($days_old_in_seconds/86400));
    if ($days_old < 3) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $("#notification").addClass("notification-highlight"); 
        });
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

I tried

```
<?php 
$post_type = get_post_type();
if (($days_old < 3) && ($post_type == "news")) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $("#notification").addClass("notification-highlight"); 
        });
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Where is this script being run?

Comment: Outside of the loop.

Comment: I have a feeling this should be inside of the loop. How would I target a specific post type?

Comment: @ZachShallbetter I see you've been back to edit your question. Did you try the new_post_alert() callback function hooked to wp_footer that I posted? I did test this and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? (Add to your theme's functions.php file, or to a plugin.)

```
function new_post_alert() {
    global $post;
    $ageunix = get_the_time( 'U' );
    $days_old_in_seconds = time() - $ageunix;
    $days_old = $days_old_in_seconds / 86400;
    $post_type = get_post_type();

    if ( ( $days_old < 3 ) && ( 'news' === $post_type ) ) { ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                $("#notification").addClass("notification-highlight");
                //alert('new!');
            });
        </script><?php
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'new_post_alert' );
```

Comment: Any reason the third and fourth lines are there?  They don't seem to do anything.

Comment: Hi Manny. You're right. I went ahead and removed the extra lines. I didn't really scrutinize the date stuff from the original code and just tossed it into a function so that it could be hooked. Still room for improvement here... On the date stuff, maybe: $days_old = (int) ( ( time() - get_the_time( 'U', $post->ID ) ) / 86400 ); Thinking about it even more, it would probably be better to hook into post_class rather than using JS for adding that notification class too. Even then, there's still room for improvement here.  Anywhoo, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Which template are you doing this in?  You can use global $post with a CPT, as long as you are inside a loop when you call the function.

Specifically, you might consider putting your code in the loop in the single-news.php template.